# What is the Visual Studio equivalent of the Eclipse import suggestion feature?

Tags: visual-studio, eclipse, import

Does anyone know if Visual Studio 2005, 2008, or 2010 has an import suggestion feature like Eclipse does? Maybe I am blatantly overlooking it, but I love Eclipse's auto-suggestions and particularly the import suggestion because I can't for the life of me remember where every single class is located and I always have to resort to Google.

Here is a screenshot of what I am talking about in Eclipse:

[image]

The quick fix feature in general is really nice in my opinion, but the import feature I find most useful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To extend the answer by sgtz, [ReSharper](http://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/features/coding_assistance.html#Importing_Namespaces) provides several features related to handling unresolved references:

- [Auto-importing namespaces](http://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/features/coding_assistance.html#Importing_Namespaces) is useful when you have an existing symbol that is not resolved due to a missing import directive. ReSharper suggests importing a type provided that at least one project in your solution has a corresponding assembly reference.
- [Import symbol completion](http://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/features/coding_assistance.html#Import_Symbol_Completion) helps you complete non-imported types as you're typing them in
- A recently added feature is [Import types for pasted code](http://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/whatsnew/index.html#ImportPasted): if you're copy-pasting a piece of code, it will import all required types in one go as soon as you've pasted
- If an unresolved symbol is actually something you don't mean to reference but instead you'd like to generate a declaration, use [Create from usage](http://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/features/code_generation.html#Create_from_Usage)

Answer (score 2):

Resharper http://www.jetbrains.com/

I am loving Resharper -- particularly the refactoring / renaming features.

Devexpress CodeRush is also supposed to be good.

Answer (score 1):

(CTRL + .) will bring up a context menu with available imports without having to use resharper :-) for all those using express editions